# How to do Items.Count -1 in xaml?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

```
<Slider Maximum="{Binding ElementName=flowControl, Path=Items.Count}" />
```

I need to return a Items.Count - 1  for the slider's maximum. How do I define this in xaml?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case you have to use a `Value Converter`.

e.g.

```
public class MaxCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value - 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You will probably need to do error handling and stuff and this is just give you a start point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a converter that substracts the 1.